# OpenGL animation using glTranslate

Tags: opengl, translation

I'm trying to make a 2D square move left, then right, in a smooth motion using `glTranslate`.

I draw the square using OpenGL using this code:

```
    void drawEnemy (RECT rect){
    glPushMatrix();

    //move enemy left then right
    glTranslatef(+right, 0.0, 0.0); //animate right
    glTranslatef(-left, 0.0, 0.0); //animate left

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(238, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(rect.x, rect.y, 0.0);
    glColor3f(128, 0.0, 128);
        glVertex3f(rect.x, rect.y+rect.h, 0.0);
    glColor3f(238, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(rect.x+rect.w, rect.y+rect.h, 0.0);
    glColor3f(128, 0.0, 128);
        glVertex3f(rect.x+rect.w, rect.y, 0.0);
        glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    }
```

I'm trying to control the length along the x-axis that it covers before returning in the opposite direction using this code:

```
    void timer(int t)
    {   
    right +=0.5f;
    if(right>=platform1.x+platform1.w)
        right-=0.5f;

    left+=0.5f;
    if(left<=platform1.x)
        left-=0.5f;

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(25,timer,0);
    }
```

I'm aware Opengl is merely a graphics package and not necessarily used for animation as such, but for the purposes of self-learning i'd really like to achieve this as simply as possible.

Currently the programme makes the square go right forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line of code:

```
if(left<=platform1.x)
    left-=0.5f;
```

What happens if `left = 0` and `platform1.x = 1`?

**Edit:**

It sounds like what you want is to track both the current position, and the direction you are moving, like this:

```
double dir = 1;
double x = platform1.x;

void timer(int t) { 
   x += dir;
   if(x < platform1.x || x > platform1.x + platform1.w) {
      dir = -dir;
      x += dir;
   }
   ...
}

void drawEnemy(RECT rect) {
   ...
   glTranslatef(x, 0.0, 0.0);
   ...
}
```

Comment: I thought that left wouldnt count down past the value of `platform.x`, then it would reduce the `left` value when it does...?

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Very nice code. Thanks so much :) I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you expressing your movement as a combination of two (`left` and `right`)? That seems overly complicated.

Just use a single `posX` variable, and increase/decrease it in response to the keypresses.

Comment: I want it to do it automatically, without keypresses. I hadnt considered using only the one variable though.